# Нет скролла для промотки страницы при использовании echo()

Tags: php, html, css

```
    body{
    text-decoration: none;
    background-color: #333;
    background:$body-bg;
    font-family: 'Titillium Web', sans-serif;
    margin:0;
    }

    ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    overflow: hidden;
    }

    li a {
    display: block;
    color: #eee;
    text-align: left;
    padding: 15px;
    margin-left:-50;
    text-decoration: none;
    }

#header {
float:left;
width:200px;
text-decoration: none;
margin-top:-16px;
background-color: #333;
color: #eee;
}

li a: hoover{
    backround-color:#eee;
}

#main{
padding-left:15;
background-color: #eee;
overflow: hidden;
height: 100%;
}

#logo {
  width: 192px;
  margin-left:-30%;
  filter:invert(100%);
  -webkit-filter: invert(100%);
  padding-left: 10px
}
#container{
    overflow: hidden;
}

#tblimg {
height: 200px;
width: 200px;

}

input, textarea{
    padding: 4px;
    border: #333 1px solid;
    border-radius: 10px;
}
#file{
    border:none;
}

td{
    padding-right: 50px;
    text-decoration: none;
}
a{
    color: #333;
    text-decoration: none;
}
.about{
    width: 500px;
    height: 500px;
}
```

---

```
<?php
    include_once('dbc.php');
    $id = $_GET['id'];
    $objectName = mysqli_fetch_assoc(mysqli_query($dbc, "SELECT objectName FROM main WHERE id = '$id'"))['objectName'];
    $objectData = mysqli_fetch_assoc(mysqli_query($dbc, "SELECT objectData FROM main WHERE id = '$id'"))['objectData'];
?>
<html><head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="CSS/style.css">
    <title>Know Your Space</title>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="container">
    <div id="header">
        <ul>
            <li><img src="solsys.png" id="logo"></li>
            <li><a href="index.php">База Проекта</a></li>
            <li><a href="add.php">Добавить статью</a></li>
            <li><a href="about.php">О проекте</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>  
    <div id="main">
    <?php 
        echo('<h2>'.$objectName.'</h2>'); 
        echo('<p><img class="about" src = "./img/'.$id.'.jpg" /></p>');
        echo('<div><font size = "5">'.$objectData.'</font></div>');
    ?>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: А где у вас "рамки"? Подробнее изъясняйтесь.

Comment: @AndreyYanov Поправил вопрос

Comment: @Damiano привидение полный пример кода.

Comment: @Vadizar Добавил скриншот

Comment: @Damiano предоставьте нормальный HTML и CSS.

Comment: @Vadizar Добавил

Answer (score 0):

Свойство `word-wrap: break-word` повесьте на `body`.

Comment: Это не совсем то, что мне нужно. Я имел ввиду, что нет скролла для промотки страницы.

Answer (score 0):

Замените:

```
#container{
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

На:

```
#container{
    overflow: auto;
    height: 100vh;
}
```

Comment: К сожалению, не помогло

Comment: @Damiano поправил

Comment: Нельзя сделать так, чтобы height изменялся, в зависимости от того, сколько текста или что-то похожее?